# how to use api in my java webapp to communicate with another webapp?

Tags: java, rest, api, web-applications

i have hosted a simple webapp in Ec-2 instance and another web app is in my local host .how can i send and receive message/parameter/data between them using a api ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use RestTemplate in spring-web.

eg:

```
String responseText = restTemplate.getForObject(url,String.class);
```